# How can I make this camera movement (with drivers)?

Tags: camera, transforms, drivers

I've been trying to orbit objects with a motion similar to the attached video, but I cannot make it. I'd like a driver based solution since some trigonometry seems to be involved. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNRhJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

All it is is 2 keyframes and the Z channel set to linear interpolation instead of bezier:

```
Keyframe 1:
X: 45
Y: 45
Z: 0

Keyframe 2:
X:-135
Y:-135
Z: 360
```

[image: corresponding animation graph]